# How to store and access data from array [product] from context?

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, react-context

I have a context which contains a fetch() method used to retieve list of products from a server.I made this context so that I could reuse the fetched array values every webpage I might need.But I am unable to do so as it gives me an error in console.

this is the code for context

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
export const ProductContext = createContext()
const ProductContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);
    const fetchData = () => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:8080/product`)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((actualData) => {
                setProduct(actualData)
                console.log(product);
            })
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, [])
    return (
        <ProductContext.Provider
            value={{ product }}>
            {props.children}
        </ProductContext.Provider>
    )
}
export default ProductContextProvider
```

and this is the error I am getting in console
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehdCl.png)

I have done this too in index.js
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBajt.png)

and this is one page I want to call the product[]

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { useContext } from 'react'
import ProductContext from '../context/ProductContext';
function Product() {
    const { product } = useContext(ProductContext)

    console.log(product);
    return (
        <div className="products-row ">
            {
                product.map((data, num) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="product" key={num}>
                            <div className="card">
                                <a target="_blank" href="/design" >
                                    <img src={data.thumbnail} alt={data.name} style={{ width: "100%" }} ></img>
                                </a>
                                <h1>{data.name}</h1>
                                <p className="price">${data.price}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    );
}

export default Product;
```

Comment: Can you share some code? Very difficult to diagnose without...

Comment: On your network tab in dev tools - are you getting a successful / 200 response code?

Comment: I am getting a 304 on that page

Comment: On the http://localhost:8080/product call?

Comment: on both  localhost:8080/product  and  localhost:3000/product

Comment: Looks like you're not hitting your endpoint? Can you set a breakpoint on that - and seee if it's executing? If not  -I'd look at your routing to see if youre sending API traffic to ther API... do you have a `setupProxy.js` file to route API requests correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's an import issue. You probably meant to use the following:

```
import { ProductContext } from '../context/ProductContext';
```

Right now, your `ProductContext` is actually `ProuductContextProvider`, which is the default export as per your code.

Comment: yes that was the problem now its fixed